# How to change Akka thread names in logging?

Tags: java, multithreading, akka

I'm using Akka version 2.4.8 and I'm trying to reduce long thread names from the logs.

Does someone knows how can I change `akka.actor.default-dispatcher` to my own thread name?

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().setName("your name");`

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Do you have a suggestion about the location to put it? I added it to all the "getProps()" but not all my actors  has this

Comment: Sorry, have no idea

Comment: What are you using for logging with Akka.  Are you using SLF4J and logback?

Comment: This is my configuration:

akka.loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
akka.loglevel = "DEBUG"
akka.logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html, Akka (via Scala) uses a ForkJoinPool by default to get its threads. If you obtain a reference to the pool, or create and supply your own, you can intercept the appropriate method in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory.html to set the name to your taste.